# What algorithm should I use for a line follower?

Tags: pid, algorithm, line-following

I actively take part in robotics competitions with my school's robotics club, and all of the line followers we use, are implemented using a PID algorithm (PD actually), but recently my electronics teacher told me to get my feet wet with fuzzy logic, he explained to me the reasons for why to use fuzzy logic (a mathematical model of a robot is hard to come up with, fuzzy logic is more "human-friendly" than PID, etc.) My question is if I should really bother with fuzzy logic or stay with PID, or maybe to change to another less known but better algorithm. The tracks that the robot has to follow are regular white over black continues ones, with no weird extras or anything like that, but most of them have marks on the sides of the beginning and end of every turn, but apart from that nothing else. So should I stick with PID or change to something else? Any advice would be very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, using only PID would be adequate. However, It also depends on the response of your motors to control signals. You can also use fuzzy logic to tune the PID parameters, which are actually time consuming.

Comment: Didn't think of that before... I'll do my best to implement that, thanks!